# Simplify the expression $^{66}C_{21}+\sum_{r=1} ^{15}\left( ^{81-r}C_{20}\right).$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Simplify the expression $^{66}C_{21}+\sum_{r=1} ^{15}\left( ^{81-r}C_{20}\right).$

The answer is $^{81} C_{21}$.

Maybe we can sum diagonals of Pascal's triangle, but I can't see the correct method.

Comment: $\binom{n}{r} +\binom{n}{r+1} = \binom{n+1}{r+1} $. Use this formula starting from $n=66$ and $r=20$ and you will arrive at the answer easily.

Comment: You can start with $^{66}C_{21}+\sum\limits_{r=66}^{80}\left(^{r}C_{20}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the [hockey stick identity](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity)? It says that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k {}^{n+i}C_n= {}^{n+k+1}C_{n+1}
$$
(I highly advise you to look at the picture that link rather than my formula, and think about what your sum looks like in the same way. It is, in my opinion, a lot more insightful than the dry formulas.)

Coupled with the fact that, with some abuse of notation, $\sum_{r=1}^{15}=\sum_{r=1}^{61}-\sum_{r=16}^{61}$ and some re-indexing, you should have enough to conclude.